# buildout or not buildout?

Tags: python-2.7, plone, buildout, zopeskel

I have a problem that when i create an add-on using  zopeskel it can't be seen in add-ons on my site. Similar with zopepy - cant import the package. 
Here is my buildout.cfg:

```
[buildout] 
extends = 
        http://dist.plone.org/release/4.1/versions.cfg
parts = 
        instance 
        zopeskel 
        zopepy 


eggs-directory=../buildout-cache/eggs 
download-cache=../buildout-cache/downloads 

develop = 
        src/* 

[instance] 
recipe = plone.recipe.zope2instance 
user = admin:admin 
eggs = Plone 

[zopeskel] 
recipe = zc.recipe.egg 
eggs = 
    ZopeSkel 
    zopeskel.diazotheme 
    zopeskel.dexterity 
    Plone 

[zopepy] 
recipe = zc.recipe.egg 
eggs = Plone 
interpreter = zopepy 
scripts = zopepy 


[versions] 
Cheetah = 2.2.1 
ZopeSkel = 2.21.2 
zopeskel.dexterity = 1.5.2 
zopeskel.diazotheme = 1.1
```

I'm using  plone3_theme template. Make some changes to setup.py. Than i create a directory src and move the package to it.

```
./bin/buildout 
Develop: '/home/demonoid67/iPlone4/zinstance/src/collective.plonelearning' 
Updating instance. 
Updating zopeskel. 
Updating zopepy. 
./bin/instance fg 
2013-08-03 14:35:07 INFO ZServer HTTP server started at Sat Aug  3 14:35:07 2013 
        Hostname: 0.0.0.0 
        Port: 8080 
2013-08-03 14:35:09 WARNING ZODB.blob (7081) Blob dir /home/demonoid67/iPlone4/zinstance/var/blobstorage/ has insecure mode setting 
2013-08-03 14:35:17 INFO Zope Ready to handle requests
```

Can someone help me? Is this a problem of my buildout.cfg or the configuration of an add-on?

Comment: I am not certain that a wildcard in `develop` (`develop = src/*`) works at all.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Changed to `develop = src/collective.plonelearning` - still doesn't work.

Comment: It was a long shot; your log does show that the package is being developed.

Comment: You didn't add the egg to the `[instance]` `eggs` entry, I see.

Comment: No, you need to add `collective.plonelearning` to your eggs entry. `mr.developer` won't manage that either.

Comment: @MartijnPieters you saved me!How can i thank you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't add the egg to your egg section:

```
[instance] 
recipe = plone.recipe.zope2instance 
user = admin:admin 
eggs = 
    Plone 
    collective.plonelearning
```

Without that entry the instance won't ever see the egg.

Comment: you saved me! How can i improve your karma? i'm new to stackoverflow!

Comment: Stick around. Contribute! You'll earn [enough reputation to vote on posts](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)  soon enough, after which you can help out by voting on questions that you find to be well written, answers that you find to be helpful.

Comment: See [How does "Reputation" work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238) for all the ways you can gain reputation. Do check out the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and you'll fit right in in no time. :-)

Comment: One caveat: If you were to upvote a lot of posts by the same user in a short amount of time, Stack Overflow will roll back those votes as part of the automated vote fraud prevention system. Vote on posts that deserve it, not because you want to reward the poster. :-)

Comment: you may also need to add a zcml=<package> for older packages